# Filter AdWords clickthroughs in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

Is there a way to filter data to include only visitors who arrived through AdWords? Is it source/medium = google/sem or source/medium = google/cpc?

Answer (score 1):

You want to create an [advanced segment](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/new-google-analytics-advanced-segments/) that you can apply to your reports.   You can create a segment that will filter the AdWords traffic.   When you apply that segment to your reports, only sessions from AdWords will be shown.  When you remove that segment, all the sessions will be shown again.

You will have to look in your **Acquisition** -> **Campaigns**-> **All Campaigns** report in GA to see what source and medium you actually use.   I use *adwords / cpc*, but it isn't the same for everybody.

1. Click **+ Add Segment**
2. Add a segment name
3. Click *Advanced* **Conditions**
4. Change the filter dropdown to **Source / Medium**
5. Set the source and medium to what you use.
6. Hit the **Save** button
7. Make sure the new segment is applied
8. Make sure no other segments are also applied
9. View the reports in which you are interested

[image]